# activate and deactivate button color and disabling

Tags: jquery, ajax

i got a little problem with the logic here, i have a **activate** and **deactivate** button that will make the ajax check if the `data[i].subj_status` or status of the `subject is = 0`the deactivate button will be gray and the activate will be blue here is the code

```
  var counter_sub = 0 ;

     var html;



              $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'add_subject.php',
                   dataType:'json',
                       data:{'func_numbr':'2'},
                    success:function (data){
                      var activator;

                      var disabler;


                       $.each(data, function(i, item) {


                        if(data[i].subj_status == "0" ){
                            activator = "";
                          disabler = "";


                        }
                        else if(data[i].subj_status == "1" ){

                          activator = "inactiveButton";
                          disabler = "disabled='disabled'";
                        }

                        html = "<tr>";

                        html += "<td><lable>Subject: </label><input type='text' name='subject["+counter_sub+"]' rel='"+data[i].subj_id+"' value='"+data[i].subj_name+"'></td>";
                        html += "<td><input type='button' id='activate' name='active' class='button active "+activator+"' value='Active' "+disabler+"> ";
                        html += "<input type='button' id='inactivate' name='active' class='button inactive "+activator+"' value='Inactive'></td>";
                        html += "</tr>";
               $('#curr-elem-tble').append(html);

               counter_sub = counter_sub +1;
              });
                    }     
             });
```

css:

```
.inactiveButton{

background:gray !important;
cursor:text;

}
```

but unfortunately if the status is equals to 1 they both became blue. plsss help me guys. tnx in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

use with escape sequence like

```
disabler = "disabled=\"disabled\"";
```

Comment: im supposed to make activate button gray if status is equals to 1 but the inactive is blue and make the active button blue  and inactive is gray if status is 0